# Graph theory question about average degree

Tags: graph-theory

The average degree of $G = (V, E)$ is $\frac{\sum_{v\in V}d(v)}{|V|}$. Let $G = (V, E)$ be a
graph with average degree $d$ and without isolated vertices.

Must there be a vertex $v ∈ V$ so that the average degree of the neighbours
of $v$ is at most $d$?

I know this is a classic problem in graph theory, but I just can't seem to solve it. I already showed that if we replace "at most" with "at least" then the answer is "Yes". I also know, that the answer to this question must be "No".

If such vertex doesn't exist, then $\forall v \in V$ we have that $$\sum_{w \in \Gamma(v)}d(w)>d\cdot d(v)$$

Summing up all those inequalities gives

$$|V|\sum_{v \in V}d^2(v)>(\sum_{v \in V}d(v))^2$$

Hence by Cauchy-Schwarz we need not all of the degrees to be equal but I don't think this helps

I also tried to construct counterexamples using some form of symmetry by isolating $2$ vertices and trying to join all of the others to them, but to no avail.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the answer is no, then a single counterexample suffices.

Here is one such graph ([source](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=548)):

[image]

Here, there are three vertices of degree $1$ and three vertices of degree $3$; the average degree is $2$. For the vertices in the middle, the average degree of their neighbors is $\frac{1+3+3}{3} = \frac73 > 2$, and for the vertices on the outside, the average degree of their neighbors is $3$.

Comment: A very nice example! Thanks a lot!